# how to compare datetime to str or how to convert it both?

Tags: python, datetime

i dont know the correct syntax for this but this is the error **if now <= Run4End and now >= Run4Start:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'**

````
Run4Start = "23:00:00"
Run4End = "00:00:00"
Run4Start = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
Run4End = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

if now <= Run4End and now >= Run4Start:```
````

Comment: Can you edit your question to include examples of what `now` and `Run4Start` and `Run4End` are? Like, their exact values.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores`style. What do you understand from that error message? I’m voting to close this, it’s a trivial issue, and there are already plenty of resources available on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a datetime object with a string object, which is not allowed. Call the `to_datetime` method in `pandas` to convert the string to a datetime object.

Do:

```py
import pandas as pd

now = pd.datetime.now()
Run4Start = "23:00:00"
Run4End = "00:00:00"
Run4Start = pd.to_datetime(Run4Start)
Run4End = pd.to_datetime(Run4end)


now <= Run4End and now >= Run4Start
```